# How do I eliminate whitespace in parent-child hierachy matrix?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a hierachy of parent child elements, but when I try to add the name of the element beside it, whitespace is followed. I tried to advance filter but it did not work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsGE1.png)